# boxplot for time series data in R

Tags: r

This is my sample data looks like,I have monthly data all the way till 2018 with different state_ID's associated with different city_ID.

```
structure(list(state_ID = c("00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", 
"00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", 
"00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", 
"00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", 
"00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", 
"00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", 
"00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", "00001", 
"00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", 
"00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", 
"00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", 
"00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", 
"00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", 
"00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", "00002", 
"00002", "00002", "00002", "00002"), city_ID = c(436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 436L, 
436L, 436L), DATE_ = structure(c(1.404e+09, 1406419200, 1409443200, 
1411862400, 1414281600, 1417305600, 1419724800, 1422144000, 1424563200, 
1427587200, 1430006400, 1433030400, 1435449600, 1437868800, 1440892800, 
1443312000, 1445731200, 1448755200, 1451174400, 1454198400, 1456617600, 
1459036800, 1461456000, 1464480000, 1466899200, 1469923200, 1472342400, 
1474761600, 1477785600, 1480204800, 1482624000, 1485648000, 1488067200, 
1490486400, 1493510400, 1495929600, 1498348800, 1501372800, 1503792000, 
1506211200, 1509235200, 1511654400, 1514678400, 1517097600, 1519516800, 
1521331200, 1.404e+09, 1406419200, 1409443200, 1411862400, 1414281600, 
1417305600, 1419724800, 1422144000, 1424563200, 1427587200, 1430006400, 
1433030400, 1435449600, 1437868800, 1440892800, 1443312000, 1445731200, 
1448755200, 1451174400, 1454198400, 1456617600, 1459036800, 1461456000, 
1464480000, 1466899200, 1469923200, 1472342400, 1474761600, 1477785600, 
1480204800, 1482624000, 1485648000, 1488067200, 1490486400, 1493510400, 
1495929600, 1498348800, 1501372800, 1503792000, 1506211200, 1509235200, 
1511654400, 1514678400, 1517097600, 1519516800, 1521331200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), value = c(175.81640448, 175.63913856, 
176.406913536, 189.90377088, 203.23923648, 232.85606087743, 257.99215104, 
283.66071936, 271.38357504, 267.250732032, 268.928352, 275.858909184, 
296.18742528, 296.67188352, 321.60720384, 323.3726592, 304.4304192, 
317.916162048, 339.82880256, 353.526595584, 334.11075456, 374.4671808, 
384.64440576, 374.4813312, 386.65659264, 309.52533504, 338.709529860565, 
335.95442304, 291.20721344, 189.42136016, 345.55611264, 284.379576832, 
364.26294144, 348.0561024, 356.95953408, 381.45053184, 399.6471744, 
411.383721984, 341.01576384, 169.67886144, 166.71692544, 229.002507780565, 
210.709393009355, 129.83239632, 186.77904096, 199.03727138742, 
217.75355904, 202.74088512, 214.35128832, 206.65861632, 207.05547072, 
230.90021831743, 260.32053504, 280.698912, 278.942976, 292.585402368, 
295.38779904, 309.370555392, 309.17826432, 322.06284672, 317.232003072, 
348.15669888, 328.85735424, 440.925229056, 452.2647936, 505.882254336, 
512.65638528, 533.06049024, 563.41078272, 563.734646784, 555.21101184, 
459.154031616, 511.35196690356, 518.53857792, 237.594366592, 
265.52476272, 26.70911584, 570.316075008, 560.95298688, 531.25721472, 
540.957133824, 534.50769024, 579.9181248, 591.968553984, 318.88770064, 
244.57011072, 229.676840448, 301.25467474356, 314.062592568545, 
152.38488576, 114.50917472, 170.496469876475)), row.names = c(NA, 
-92L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("state_ID", 
"city_ID"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:45, 46:91), group_sizes = c(46L, 
46L), biggest_group_size = 46L, labels = structure(list(state_ID = c("00001", 
"00002"), city_ID = c(436L, 436L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("state_ID", 
"city_ID"), drop = TRUE))
```

Would like to get boxplots for each group(grouped by state_ID) and detect the outliers
Can someone help me to do in R

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you are asking. Also, when using TLAs (Three Letter Acronyms) or jargon it is good clarify the meaning of the TLA instead of assuming everyone understands the meaning. It's also unclear what `str(my_dat)` has to do with the question.

Comment: you probably need to narrow down your question and add a proper dataset.

Comment: I would like to show boxplots and detect the outliers@keithpjolley and I added str(my_dat) just to know what kind of columns am having in my data set

Comment: Edited the question @ed_sans Can you help me in getting boxplots for each state and find the outliers or any seasonal trend to show about the data

Comment: If you have a data frame called df, you could use: library('ggplot2')
ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = city_ID, y = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~state_ID, scales = "free"). Not sure how you want to use the date